# grant permissions to multiple codebases

Tags: java, security, policyfiles

Is it possible to grant same permissions to unrelated codebases (e.g. I can not use wildcards)?

For example I have following permission configuration:

```
grant codebase "file:/somepath1/code.jar" {
  permission my.class.Permission1;
  permission my.class.Permission2;
  permission my.class.Permission3;
};
```

I want to grant the same permission set also to `/somepath2/code2.jar` and to `path3/code3.jar`.

Is it possible to do with single grant section?

Answer (score 2):

From what I know there are 2 ways to achieve what you wish:
1.sing you jars with some certificate and then use:

```
grant signedBy "Duke" {
       permission my.class.Paermission1;
};
```

"Duke" is an alias to certificate in tye keystore.

2.reorganize you jars into folders and then use:

```
grant codeBase "file:/somepath/subpath1/-" {
      permission my.class.Paermission1;
};
```

"/-" matches all files (both class and JAR files) in the directory and recursively all files in subdirectories contained in that directory

Check this for details [PolicyFiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html#FileSyntax)